# Need help preventing that my ships will overlap with each other in a 2d array

Tags: overlap

Im creating a battleship game for a school project and ive tried for very long to place my ships randomly and not overlap with each other. Ive tried various booleans and if statements but it doesnt seem to work.Its something wrong with the if statement I  think and I need more code there.

My ships prints out ok with the size but sometimes they overlap.

Id appreciate if someone could help me out !:D

public class Game {

```
private int row;
private int col;

private Ship[][] board;
private ArrayList<Ship> ships;

private int shotsFired;
private int hitCount;
private int shipsSunk;
private int placedShips;
private int shipNumber;

public Game() {

    shotsFired = 0;
    hitCount = 0;
    shipsSunk = 0;
    placedShips = 0;
    shipNumber = 5;

    ships = new ArrayList<>();
    ships.add(new Battleship(5));
    ships.add(new Fighter(4));
    ships.add(new Destroyer(3));
    ships.add(new Cruiser(2));
    ships.add(new Submarine(1));
}

public void createBoard(Ship ship) {

    row = 10;
    col = row;

    board = new Ship[row][col];
    //creates the battle field, fills with empty ships
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        Arrays.fill(board[i], null);
    }
    placeShips();
}

public void placeShips() {
    int occupied = 0;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < ships.size(); i++) {
        boolean direction = random.nextBoolean();
        if (direction) {
            int x = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            int y = (int) (Math.random() * (10 - ships.get(i).getSize()));
            for (int j = 0; j < ships.get(i).getSize(); j++) {
                if (board[x][y + j] == null) {
                    board[x][y + j] = ships.get(i);
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            int x = (int) (Math.random() * (10 - ships.get(i).getSize()));
            int y = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
            for (int j = 0; j < ships.get(i).getSize(); j++) {
                if (board[x + j][y] == null) {
                    board[x + j][y] = ships.get(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REpeJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a function that "reserves" the space for your next placement of a ship before actually putting it in.

So first, create a matrix of 2*2 for your Game class to store the starting and ending positions.

After that get an initial position and save it to the first array in the matrix, then probe the board for empty spaces in any of the four directions (as you are already doing in your code), and when you reach the final place save that position in your second array in the matrix. If you find an occupied space, just end the function and call it again until you get a result.
Should look something like this:

```js
...
position = null;
while (position == null) {
  position = getPosition(i); // Where i is the position you are using to take a ship from the list
}
...


public void getPosition(i) {
    int[][] positionArray = [];
    Random random = new Random();
    boolean direction = random.nextBoolean();
    if (direction) {
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        int y = (int) (Math.random() * (10 - ships.get(i).getSize()));
        positionArray[0] = [x,y];
        for (int j = 0; j < ships.get(i).getSize(); j++) {
            if (board[x][y + j] != null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                y = y + 1;
            }
        }
        positionArray[1] = [x,y];
    }
    else {
        int x = (int) (Math.random() * (10 - ships.get(i).getSize()));
        int y = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        positionArray[0] = [x,y];
        for (int j = 0; j < ships.get(i).getSize(); j++) {
            if (board[x + j][y] != null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                x = x + 1;
            }
        }
        positionArray[1] = [x,y];
    }
    return positionArray;
}
```

After that, you will need a bit of code to set the ship from the starting position to the final position but, as an ex-professor myself, I will let you solve that part.
Hope that helped, have fun!

Note: I didn't test the code so I'm not 100% sure if the syntax is correct, so don't just copy and paste.

Comment: As a side note, you could also make a bigger positionArray and save ALL positions for the placement to make it easier and not having to do more logic to set the ship in the board.

Comment: Thanks alot for the respond!! I dont quite understand where I should use the 3 first lines of code that u did. And I wonder if I should change my code in the placeShips function ?

Comment: @SimonPizevski you use them inside the placeShips function, and you will have to remove the first for entirely. After those 3 lines, inside the function, you've got to manage the placement in a different, more simple way.

Comment: I appreciate all your help but honestly Im totally lost right now, im trying to think of a simple solution to set the ships in the placeShips(). Ive tried to loop through it with 2 loops and then set the position[x][y] to the board[x][y]. Do I need the same amount of code in the placeShips function as in the getPosition. I understand if you dont want to give me all of the clues, and I appreciate every bit of help given :)

Comment: Finally its solved! Thank your for all the help! I figured out a way to it all in the placeShips function :D

Comment: @SimonPizevski Sorry I didn't see this before, but I'm glad you made it on your own! Keep going, it only gets better :D